# Faced "This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap" in React when using react-select

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was learning how to remove(on button click) those items from react-select input that correspond to user input. But I face the error: **This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap**. Here is the button click function handler:

```
const onClearAll = () => {
  const filteredOptions = options.filter(option => {
    //Here I face that error
    return filterOption(option as any, inputValue) !== inputValue;
  });
  setValue([...value, ...filteredOptions], setValueAction);
};
```

Comment: How does `filterOption` function look like?

Comment: @Clarity, filterOption?: ((
    option: Option,
    rawInput: string
  ) => boolean) | null;

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your function signature you're comparing boolean (the return from `filterOption`) to a string, `inputValue`. So you'll either need to change `filterOption` to return a string or compare it to boolean e.g. `filterOption(option as any, inputValue) === true;`

The first option is probably smth you're looking for.